# Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm both produce the minimum spanning tree. According to the cut property, the total cost of the tree will be the same for these algorithms, but is it possible that these two algorithms give different MST with the same total cost, given that we choose it in alphabetic order when faced with multiple choices. for example, we compare max(source,dest), for edges A->B and B->C, we compare A from A->B and B from B->C.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your comparator handles the case where both edges are equal in cost and have the same max(source, dest) character, it will never declare any two edges equal. For there to be the possibility of multiple MSTs, at least two edges in the graph must be equal. Therefore, the MST is unique, and both Prim's and Kruskal's algorithm will return the same result.

On the other hand, if your comparator declares the edges A->B (cost 1) and A->C (cost 1) equal, than there is a possibility that the algorithms will generate different MSTs, depending on which edge they consider first (A->B or A->C).

Comment: It's true that for there to be the possibility of multiple MSTs, at least two edges in the graph must be equal. However, this does't mean that there's only one MST if comparator declares every edge different. Is there mathematical proof that when the comparator declares every edge different, Prim and Kruskal will necessarily generate the same MST?

Comment: To answer the above question:  if a graph G has distinct edge weights, it has a unique MST.  I think this means that no matter which node you start at for Prim's you will get the same unique MST for Kruskal's as well.

Comment: What is the basis for `Assuming that your comparator handles the case where both edges are equal in cost and have the same max(source, dest) character, it will never declare any two edges equal`? How about `min(source, dest)`? Do we need to handle it too?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible for one graph to have multiple MSTs, so long as those different representations of the MSTs have the same total weight. Otherwise, the one with the lower total weight would be the true MST and the other would no longer be an MST.

Because Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms have different steps, it is possible that they would choose different edges of the same weight during the actual traversal, yet still end with the same total weight.

However, if you add the restriction that you stated in your question (choosing the node that comes first in the alphabet) the MST for Prim's and Kruskal's should be the same tree, for each of the decisions, even if they are the same weight, would prefer the same edge for both Kruskal's and Prim's.